# Apache2 recognizes my ip address diffrently from my ip address

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ip

I want only my IP address or specific IP addresses to access a specific page.

For now, I set up my ip address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` in .htaccess file to allow access only my ip address like below. (this IP address is the value from https://www.myip.com/)

```
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
deny from all
</Files>
```

after I saved .htaccess file, I ran following command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and when i visited MYPAGE/wp-login.php, i could see the message like, `"Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.".`

so, I checked /var/log/apache2/error.log file.
There was an error log with
`[access_compat:error] [pid 12018] [client 172.aa.a.aaa:aaaaa] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wp-login.php`

This value here `172.aa.a.aaa:aaaaa` is not same with my IP address. Where does this address come from? and how can I know which value of other IP address'?

and.. Is there any way to allow IP addresses which is obtained from https://www.myip.com/ with apache2?

Thank you for reading my question, and I would really appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address you see from https://www.myip.com/ is yours *as seen from the Internet*.

If your machine and the server hosting `MYPAGE/wp-login.php` is located behind a proxy/firewall (e.g. inside a local network), then your local IP address will be different.

You can find your local IP address by using `ifconfig` command (or `ipconfig` if you are on a Windows machine).

EDIT: since the IP address logged in `error.log` is varying, you cannot use IP address restriction here. Therefore, Using `.htaccess` and `htpasswd` would be more appropriate to secure your login page. You can find an example [here](https://docs.freistilbox.com/security/access_by_login/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have this problem. I checked my ip with `ifconfig` command, but it is different from the IP in error.log..

Comment: and this IP address in error.log is changing flexibly when accessing after some time, although only I am accessing the server with same IP.

Comment: just updated my answer above. Please give a try and let me know.